# How to design custom modal dialogs as regular view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I often need a custom modal dialog that does not fill the whole screen, such as the action sheet that ships with the iOS SDK. This dialog has to handle some tricky scenarios and conditions, for example the interface rotation, and also often carries a lot of code to handle the user choices. Therefore it seems quite desirable to build the dialog as a regular view+controller combination and get it working like a first-class citizen in the UI.

The system modal controller API (`presentModalViewController:animated:`) is quite limited in this regard, for example it insists on hiding the controller under the modal one and forces you to use the predefined animations with little controler over them.

The controller containment API looks quite promising, as it allows for several views on the screen at once, each governed by a different controller. (Which is exactly the situation with a modal dialog atop of a regular view controller.) But the interplay with the standard container controllers (like `UINavigationController`) is rocky, [as I have found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512911).

Does anybody have a working technique that would make it possible to keep the non-fullscreen modal dialogs as regular view controllers and have them play nicely with the rest of the UI?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want it to be a view controller, you will have to use the containment api introduced in iOS 5, which it sounds as if you've already been toying with. I completely agree with you - it is sort of rocky, and therefore I usually choose a different approach.

I create a controller that subclasses NSObject and add it as an object in interfacebuilder. Then I setup the controller to have both a container- and a contentView. I create an initialization method which takes the containerView as a parameter, and do what I would normally have done in viewWillAppear in that method. The initialization method, I call from the view controller, which is responsible for handing the containerView to the modal controller.

Once initialized, the modal controller has the responsibility of it's container and content views. It will simply remove them from their superviews once the modal controller should dismiss.

Here is a method I call from my main view controller in an iPad app. Abstract from the irrelevant stuff :)

```
- (IBAction)showAddProduct:(UIButton *)sender {
  UIView *containterForAddProduct = self.darken;
  containterForAddProduct.alpha = 0;
  [self.view addSubview:containterForAddProduct];
  [self.addEditProductController beginAddingProductInContainerView:containterForAddProduct andManagedObjectContext:self.gridController.managedObjectContext];
}
```

Comment: The downside is that such controller is not a part of the controller hierarchy and therefore does not receive the rotation and appearance calls? That’s what I’m trying to avoid, I’d love the modal dialog to be a regular part of the UI, just like it would be when presented using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Zould, if you want it to rotate along with its parent viewcontroller, there is no problem it will do so automatically. If you do however want it to behave in a different way than its parent viewcontroller you will have to implement a method for willRotate yourself and call it from the parent viewcontrollers delegate method.

Comment: That’s it, I want to be able to exchange the view’s content completely, and generally do whatever crazy stuff you can do in a regular view controller. Manually relaying all the information and callbacks from the parent view controller sucks – that’s why I’m trying to come up with some “system” solution. The containment API is *very* close, if it were not for the problems with `UINavigationController`.

Comment: If you take a look at the number of methods you have to forward, it's really not that many :) But I understand your concern, and I was desperately searching for a similar solution before I chose to go with the approach described above. I simply found it to be the cleanest, please let me know though if you discover something.